# .NET 4.5 and .NET Core - Authentication Legacy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm starting to work with ASP.NET Core but I still have legacy projects, so I'm going through the following problem.

I have a project in .NET Framework 4.5 that is responsible for authenticating all my other applications.
This project uses Microsoft Owin for authentication:

Authentication project:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider()
};

// Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new AppOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
});
```

In other applications the token generation part is not added, only

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new AppOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
});
```

In both web.config:

```
<machineKey validationKey="myValidationKey" decryptionKey="myDecryptionKey" validation="SHA1" />
```

Is it possible for the new .NET Core project to maintain the same authentication by validating the token generated by the authentication application?

Comment: In other words, you wan to reuse your Authorization Server in your new (or better re-written) applications? Yes this is possible. The code in the consuming app will differ a little (new API) but will still be similar.

Comment: Yes, my new .NET Core application must authenticate to .NET 4.5. I saw that in .NET Core the machinekey is no longer used. How could I make my new application "understand" the received token? May you help me?

Comment: Someone may help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found two solution:

1. Replace machine key https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey?view=aspnetcore-2.1
2. Change AccessTokenFormat to generate a token using JWT.

In both options, you need to refactored the projects with .NetFramework

I developed the second option, you can check it in https://github.com/aloji/JwtSecurity

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who are looking for a solution for .NET Core 3.1

1. Install [AspNetTicketBridge](https://github.com/dmarlow/AspNetTicketBridge)
2. Create a custom Authentication handler

```
public class NET45AuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public NET45AuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, 
        UrlEncoder encoder, 
        ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {

    }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized");

            string authorizationHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authorizationHeader))
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized");

            if(!authorizationHeader.StartsWith("bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized");

            string token = authorizationHeader.Substring("bearer".Length).Trim();

            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized");

            string validationKey = "YourMachineKey||WebConfig-ValidationKey";
            string decryptionKey = "YourMachineKey||WebConfig-DecryptionKey";

            /*
             * Defaults to 
             * DECRIPTION: AES
             * Validation Algorithm: HMACSHA1
            */
            var ticket = MachineKeyTicketUnprotector.UnprotectOAuthToken(token, decryptionKey, validationKey);// DEFAULT TO Decription AES 

            var newTicket = AuthenticationTicketConverter.Convert(ticket, "Basic");

            return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(newTicket));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized");
        }   
    }
}
```

3. Register the Custom Authentication Handler in the Startup > ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddAuthentication("Basic")
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, NET45AuthenticationHandler>("Basic", null);

    //...
}
```

4. Also update your StartUp > Configure, this must be put between UseRouting and UseEndpoint

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    //...
}
```